# How to parse years of experience from resume from Experience field present in resume?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am working with a resume parser in Django that can parse all the data but I want to calculate years of experience from the dates mentioned in the resume in the experience field I have come up with a strategy that we can parse the experience section and parse all the dates but I am facing a hard time to implement it. Is there any other way to calculate the experience from different dates and add all the dates?

```
def extract_experience(resume_text):
'''
Helper function to extract experience from resume text

:param resume_text: Plain resume text
:return: list of experience
'''
    wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# word tokenization 
    word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(resume_text)

# remove stop words and lemmatize  
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words and 
    wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) not in stop_words] 
    sent = nltk.pos_tag(filtered_sentence)

# parse regex
   cp = nltk.RegexpParser('P: {<NNP>+}')
   cs = cp.parse(sent)

# for i in cs.subtrees(filter=lambda x: x.label() == 'P'):
#     print(i)

   test = []

   for vp in list(cs.subtrees(filter=lambda x: x.label()=='P')):
    test.append(" ".join([i[0] for i in vp.leaves() if len(vp.leaves()) >= 2]))

# Search the word 'experience' in the chunk and then print out the text after it
    x = [x[x.lower().index('experience') + 10:] for i, x in enumerate(test) if x and 
    'experience' in x.lower()]
    return x
```

This function extracts the experience from previous companies which includes text so I want to extract years or months of experience from it and store it in a field.

**This is the main question**
This is the text filed and I want to extract years from this and add all the years and months in any format? Is there any way to specify start and end dates and add them and return total years of experience?

> SpiceJet(08/2021 - 10/2021), ❖, Leading Indian airlines company worked and Developed an analytical tool that, can regulate data  .(02/2022 - 03/2022 ), ❖, Tutorbin is an integrated online tutoring platform serving as a one-stop, solution AI and Machine learning Intern, Dawn DigiTech (04/2022 -present), ❖, This company digitally transform multiple front- and back-office

I have another sub-question in this if we calculate total experience how can we calculate relevant experience if I need only those dates which match the Job description and add only those dates is there any way we can calculate those years of experience.
For example: if I have 3 years of hotel management experience and 1 year of software developer experience and I want to take only relevant software developer experience and count those years only how we can do that. and store in relevant experience field.

This is the current output but the experience field function is not there .

How can we make a function to extract years of experience and relevant experience from resume?

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkTJj.png)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. The question is kind of confused. At which step are you stuck exactly? Could you please focus the question on that particular step? Could you show an example text that contains experience, and the output you'd want from that?

Comment: hi, @Stef I have added the main question and the output that I want already mentioned there is the last line where the image link is provided I want output in integer or float value which would mention total years and months of experience. if there is anything I needed to add please let me know.